# Dynamic URL Routing not working with ASP.NET Web forms site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url-routing, routeconfig

I have website in asp.net web forms. It uses url friendly structure. suppose I have url **www.site.com/experience/experience-category**. Here there are two different pages experience & experience-category. Now whenever I try to access this url **www.site.com/experience/experience-category** it doeson't shows me this page. It showing me www.site.com/experience page. How this can be resolved?

RouteConfig

```
Public Module RouteConfig
    Public Sub RegisterRoutes(routes As RouteCollection)
        Dim settings = New FriendlyUrlSettings()
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings)

        routes.MapPageRoute("experience-category", "experience/{name}", "~/experience-category.aspx") 'For Experience Category
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of things you can do.

What `routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings)` basically does is adding 2 Routes to your route collection.

Your problem is that you have an .aspx (experience.aspx) with the same name as part of the route url you set up ( `experience/{name}` ).
The routing will look for the first match in your route collection (in this case it'll be your `EnableFriendlyUrls` routes).

If you want to overcome this you can do the following:

## 1.Execute routes.MapPageRoute before routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings) :

```
    Public Module RouteConfig
    Public Sub RegisterRoutes(routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.MapPageRoute("experience-category", "experience/{name}", "~/experience-category.aspx") 'For Experience Category

        Dim settings = New FriendlyUrlSettings()
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings)

    End Sub
End Module
```

This will put this rule first, beating the FriendlyUrlSettings:

Or

## 2. Use insert to insert your rule at the start of the routes collection (instead of MapPageRoute):

```
    Dim settings = New FriendlyUrlSettings()
    settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent
    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings)

    Dim overwrExperienceUrl As String = "experience/{name}"
    Dim overwrExperiencePRH As New PageRouteHandler("~/experience-category.aspx")
    Dim overwrExperienceRoute As New Route(overwrExperienceUrl, overwrExperiencePRH)
    routes.Insert(0, overwrExperienceRoute)
```

## 3.Avoid a match with the EnableFriendlyUrl routing rules:

Move your control(s) (Experience.aspx) to a folder so it won't interfere in this case.